# How to delete an object that is a reference type from an ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, powershell, .net-core, arraylist, reference-type

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve deletion of an object inside an ArrayList when the object is a reference type.

Consider the following code:

```
$leftTable =  Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path "C:\temp\linux_left.csv" 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$rightTable =  Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path "C:\temp\linux_right.csv"
$finalTable = @()

foreach($line in $leftTable) {   

    $matched = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $line -DifferenceObject $rightTable -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Property 'asset.name','definition.id','definition.name','state'| Select-Object 'asset.name','definition.id','definition.name','state'
    if($matched)
    {
        $finalTable += $matched
        $rightTable.Remove($matched)
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I make `$matched` matches structurally what matched in `$rightTable` ?

I know it has something to do with Object.Equals() method that is testing for reference equality when the Remove() method is trying to match what I want to delete, but I really don't see how can I make this working with code above?

Comment: Do you actually have a property called ```asset.name```, or do you have a property called ```asset``` which has its own ```name``` property? ```Compare-Object``` won’t traverse the object hierarchy to compare nested properties…

Comment: The property is really called `asset.name` so `Compare-Object` works here.

Comment: This may be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777): `Compare-Object` is designed to compare two _collections_, so comparing a single line against a collection in a loop seems counter-productive. Note that when you use `-Property` for specifying what properties to compare by, the output objects are _not_ the objects from the input collections, but _custom objects_ with the values of the specified properties. `-PassThru` changes that, but - with `-IncludeEqual` - only returns the `-ReferenceObject` argument's objects.

Comment: I suggest updating your question with what you're actually trying to achieve, using sample input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Posting from a phone so can’t give a full description right now, but the sample below works on tio.run…

```
$left = @"
aaa, bbb, ccc
a1, b1, c1
a2, b2, c2
"@ | convertfrom-csv

$right = @"
aaa, bbb, ccc
a1, b1, c1
a3, b3, c3
"@ | convertfrom-csv

$results = @()
foreach( $item in $left )
{
    $matched = @(
        $right `
            | where-object {
                ($_.aaa -eq $item.aaa) -and 
                ($_.bbb -eq $item.bbb) -and
                ($_.ccc -eq $item.ccc) 
            }
    )

    # don”t use += in production code
    # (this is just for demo purposes)
    $results += $matched

    $right = @( $right `
        | where-object {
            $_ -notin $matched
        }
    )

}

"results = "
$results | format-table

"right = "
$right | format-table
```

Output:

```
results = 

aaa bbb ccc
--- --- ---
a1  b1  c1

right = 

aaa bbb ccc
--- --- ---
a3  b3  c3
```

Basically it finds the objects in `$right` that match each item in `$left` and then creates a new array with those items filtered out…

Comment: I followed what you suggested and instead of trying to delete the entry in the ArrayList, I  overwritten `$rightTable` by filtering it out. Thanks a lot!